# Proving that the maximum of the set $A$ = sup $A$, which is a subset of an ordered set $(S, <)$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $(S, <)$ be an ordered set and $A \subset S$. Suppose that $A$ contains a largest element, which we denote by max $A$. Prove that sup $A$ exists in $S$ and equals max $A$.

Comment: How would you go on to prove this? I am stuck

Answer (score 0):

By definition, $\max A \in A$ such that $$(\forall a \in A): a\leq\max A$$
From this, $\max A$ is an upper bound for $A$. If $y$ is any other upper bound for $A$, then $$(\forall a \in A): a \leq y$$ In particular, $\max A \in A$, so  $\max A \leq y$, concluding $\max A=\sup A$

Comment: actually, if $y$ is an upper bound for $A$, then $a\leq s$ for $a\in A$, with this we obtain $\max A\leq y$ for any upper bound for $A$. If $y$ is the least upper bound for $A$ (i.e. $y=\sup A$) then $y\leq \max A$, since $\max A$ itself is an upper bound for $A$. Thus $\sup A= y=\max A$

Comment: Would proving that $\mbox{sup } A \in S$ be justifiable from the fact that $A \subset S$?

Comment: @edgaralonso This right here:

$$\text{If } y \text{ is the least upper bound for } A$$

needs to be justified.  The justification is just what Chinnapparaj showed, though all the strict inequalities need to be changed to $\leq$ (or be changed to their equivalent logical statements with respect to $<$)

Comment: @BrianMoehring i dont understand, you are saying that he is proving the existence of the upper bound? That's clear to me, my only concern is that if we only use $<$, then we obtain $\sup A> \max A$ and $\max A\geq \sup A$ and that does not yields $\max A = \sup A$.

Comment: @edgaralonso Actually, $\sup A > \max A$ and $\max A \geq \sup A$ _does_ logically yield $\max A = \sup A$ but it also logically yields that I'm the king of England, being a contradiction and all...  There were a few parts to my comment but the only two important ones right now are the following: (1) Chinnapparaj's post is currently wrong, but it is fixed if we simply replace all instances of $<$ with $\leq.$  (2) If I took your original post as a separate proof, then you assumed the existence of $\sup A$ without proving it exists.

Comment: @BrianMoehring yes, i am more than aware of that. That why i posted my argument in Chinnapparaj's post (instead of posting another answer), to complement his answer...